# Uploading svg and pdf in the new media gallery

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

Does anyone know, why in the old media gallery it was possible to upload svg and pdf and it will show on media gallery UI, and in the new one, it uploads, but doesnt show.

I know that it saves data to media_gallery_asset, which it didnt do before. But if i run sync media gallery, then they show in the UI. But if i upload from the UI, then it doesnt save data to media_gallery_asset, unless it is jpeg, png...

I have been trying to debug, to find out, where the saveAssetsinterface is being called from when saving data to media_gallery_assets, but havent had any luck yet.

Comment: Just curious why M2 does not have it as it was presented before. It's not a simple thing to add a new file type as it must manageable from the Media Gallery itself. 
@DritonCazimi Does any solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml` file:

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="resizeParameters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="height" xsi:type="number">75</item>
            <item name="width" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
                <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
                <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
                <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
                <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        ...
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Those are all allowed to upload file extensions. To make svg and pdf possible to upload, create your own module, and add di.xml (`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

EDIT:

Additionally, that part comes from `vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization/etc/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\MediaGallerySynchronization\Model\FetchMediaStorageFileBatches">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchSize" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
        <argument name="fileExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You should add your custom extensions in that file too, so it make that files recognizable.

Place that in your `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\MediaGallerySynchronization\Model\FetchMediaStorageFileBatches">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="fileExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">pdf</item>
            <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">svg</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: I'm able to upload, i'm just not have luck to save the data to media_gallery_asset.

But i i'll look in the pointed place.

Update: Yeah already been there, done that. It doesnt affect it. They still not getting uploaded to media_gallery_asset

Comment: Ok, I will look deeper in that topic then ;) What Magento version are you using?

Comment: Im on magento 2.4.2

Comment: Same problem here, I am able to upload pdf to the gallery but the asset is not shown in it. magento 2.4.3 @DritonCazimi, you found a solution? can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Create a di.xml in a adminhtml folder in your module and then put this information in the di

```
<type name="Magento\MediaGalleryIntegration\Plugin\SaveImageInformation">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">svg</item>
                <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">pdf</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Then it will call the synchronization which save data to the media_gallery_asset.

Because when it call the media asset it will look after image extensions. If they are not delivered then it will skip the extension you are trying to save in media_gallery_asset

The code that checks for the extension in SaveImageInformation

```
 private function isApplicable(string $path): bool
    {
        try {
            return $path
                && !$this->isPathExcluded->execute($path)
                && preg_match('#\.(' . implode("|", $this->imageExtensions) . ')$# i', $path);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->log->critical($exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pdf files are uploaded but I still can't see them in the gallery.